# First push to github repo generated 765 untracked or modified files

Tags: git, flutter, github, visual-studio-code

This is the first time I tried to push and create new repository from vscode button at the bottom left.
Once that was done, I was shocked to 765 files. Most of them were untracked.
I don't know what these files are and where did they come from.
There's R.java files. The gitignore file was wiped (I think), the build folder, .flutter-plugins are added.
Is this safe to do?

the gitignore changes specifically made me worry.

[image]

the git status output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that most of the files not indexed in the git repository are from the `/build/` folder. When you compile your project, the compiled files and finished apps are stored here. They should not be included in the git repo.

I suspect that because of the changes to your `.gitignore` file, you will now see all of these files. It could be that some of your `.gitignore` file was accidentally deleted. My file is 74 lines long and yours seems to be only 44 lines long.

This would have to be the default file, which would make the unindexed files disappear again:

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
```

Comment: I didn't touch the .gitignore file. It's the usual .gitignore file that is generated once I initialize a repository from vscode. What I don't understand why did the push to github change the .gitignore file. I  have fixed it by delete the github repo and undoing all the changes. I will stick to the terminal for adding a remote repository.