# Why does vs code show so many untracked files whenever I try to see the code for a built-in flutter widget?

Tags: git, flutter, dart, github

While working in Flutter, sometimes I wish to see how a certain built-in or third-party widget works internally. And when I do ctrl+click on my vs code on that widget and hope to see its code, vs code then suddenly shows me like 140-150 untracked files. It only happens when I try to view the code for built-in or third-party widgets.
Help me!!!!
Thanks...[image]

Comment: It doesn't happens with me. but I think it's because when we open code of widgets flutter / extension is downloading the code files and related content in the current directory for temporary purpose. and then when we closes it goes like this

Comment: How does your .gitignore file look like?    see if this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604443/first-push-to-github-repo-generated-765-untracked-or-modified-files

Comment: @Remoo here's how my .gitignore file looks like.. https://www.github.com/Biplab-Dutta/notes_app_DDD/tree/master/.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the `flutter` repo *(the one above the git commit message text field)* and `close repository`.

Comment: Sorry @rapaterno, it comes back again and again after closing it

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and found this question.

VS code has an [option to hide a specific repository](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=//%20List%20of%20git%20repositories%20to%20ignore.%0A%20%20%22git.ignoredRepositories%22%3A%20%5B%5D%2C) non-related to a `.gitignore` file existence nor its contents.

The steps are:

1. `Files` ➜ `Preferences` ➜ `Settings`
2. ➜ `User` / `Workspace`, depends on the scope needed to be applied to.
3. Search for `Git: Ignored Repositories`.
4. Append your local `flutter` repository location, in my case: `c:\flutter`
5. Close it manually for the last time, either by restarting VS code or by right clicking it and pressing `close repository`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in VSC you can hide the untracked files, and remove them from several actions, e.g. commit.

You can manage untracked files separately by using the Git: `Untracked Changes` setting.
In the `Settings` search for `Untracked Changes`, and select `hidden`.

[image: Git:Untracked Changes]

- Choose the `separate` option, if you'd like to see untracked files in a separate group in the Source Control view.
- Choose `mixed` if you want them to be included in a commit.
- Choose `hidden` if you'd like to never see them.

Answer (score -1):

Your SDK is actually something cloned from Github or something that has been connected with Github. Any change in that file may reflect in our files too. Source Control feature of VS Code actually follows that repo. Simply close that source control by minimizing it. Usually, Flutter with Source Control enabled to have these problems.